# Transformation of Parameter

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S=\mathbb{S}^2$ and let $F_1(x_1,x_2)=\left(x_1,x_2,\sqrt{1-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}\right)$ and $F_2(x_1,x_3)=\left(x_1,\sqrt{1-x_1^2-x_3^2},x_3\right)$ two parametrizations. Furthermore, $(u_1,u_2)\in U_1=\{u:\|u\|<1\}$ and $H=F_2^{-1}\circ F_1$. Find explicitly $H$ and show that $H$ is differentiable in $U_1$.

Hello, my problem is how define $H(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Does the below help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the inverse of $F_2$. First write,

$$F_2(x_1,x_3) = \left(x_1, \sqrt{1-x_1^2-x_3^2},x_3\right) = \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \\ w \end{pmatrix}$$

So we need $g(u,v,w) = (x_1,x_3)$. Recalling that $(u,v,w) \in \textbf{Im}(F_2)$, take $g(u,v,w) = (u,w)$. I will show that $g$ is the right-inverse of $F_2$, and I'll leave you to show the left inverse portion. Here we have that,

\begin{align*}(F_2 \circ g)(u,v,w) &= F_2(g(u,v,w)) \\&= F_2(u,v) \\&= F_2(x_1,x_3) \\&= (u,v,w) \end{align*}

Now that we have $F_2^{-1}:=g$, we can compute $H$. I will leave you to show that $H$ is differentiable over the set $U_1$.

\begin{align*} H(x_1,x_2) &= (F_2^{-1} \circ F_1)(x_1,x_2) \\ & = F_2^{-1}\left(x_1, x_2, \sqrt{1-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}\right) \\ &= \left(x_1, \sqrt{1-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}\right) \end{align*}